# Is there a way to programatically highlight specific days?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using `FullCalendar React component` and I want to accomplish highlighting specific days. Is there a way to do this?

I tried using `Background Events`, aka. events with property `display: "background"`, but that didn't do anything.
I stumbled upon Calendar::select, but I have no idea how to call it in React.

By the way, `version 5.3.0`

Comment: The documentation is quite good, you just have to use/read it: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-cell-render-hooks

Comment: $("td[data-date="+date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"]").addClass("fc-state-highlight"); and you can style this class or you can directly use $("td[data-date="+date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"]").css("background-color", "yellow");

Comment: @Andreas No idea how to use that for my use case. I want to highlight or unhighlight them freely when the dragEventStart or dragEventStop respectively fires.

Comment: _"... when the dragEventStart or dragEventStop respectively fires"_ - Where in your question is this relevant information hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events you can do this by `setting an event object’s display property to "background"`:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  initialDate: '2014-11-10',
  initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
  events: [
    {
      start: '2014-11-10T10:00:00',
      end: '2014-11-10T16:00:00',
      display: 'background'
    }
  ]
});
```

[Here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events-demo) is working demo

Comment: I know about it, but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: You know this way is a standard way of highlighting. If it doesn't work for you,  share executable code to explore it.

Comment: You are right, I altered with eventDidMount function, it did not throw any errors cause this event does not has a proparty I was checking for, it didn't fire an error into the console, so I didn't realized it.